# Run execute_command without sudo?

Tags: docker, packer

I've installed packer in a docker with the entrypoint /bin/packer.

My host system loads the docker within a gitlab-ci.yml file und runs the packer build command. Unfortunately I can not install sudo on the host system (Openshift cluster). At the moment I get an error from packer that the command sudo is unknown (packer-qemu-build: bash: sudo is unknown).

```
"provisioners": [
{
  "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant' | {{.Vars}} sudo -S -E sh -eux '{{.Path}}'",
  "scripts": [
    "scripts/foo.sh"
  ],
  "type": "shell"
}
```

],

Can I execute the shell command without sudo? Or is the only approach to use a script as entrypoint for the docker to execute all commands within the docker where sudo can be installed?

The docker where packer is installed has sudo installed as well.